# Changing type signature of base class member based on inheriting class template

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, crtp

I have two classes, one inherits from another:

```
struct A {
    (pure?) virtual tt returns_something();
}

template <typename T>
struct B : A {
    virtual T returns_something();
}
```

How do I make this work, such that `returns_something()` has the right type signature.

I believe this is a job for the curiously recurring template pattern:

```
template <typename T>
struct A {
    pure virtual typename T::tt returns_something();
}
template <typename TT>
struct B : A<B<TT>> {
    typedef TT tt;
    virtual tt returns_something();
}
```

However, this seems to complain that "there is no type named 'tt' in B< float >"  (when I instantiate `B` with TT as a float).

Any ideas?  Is this the right approach in this case?  Is there another approach that is better suited?

note:  This is a simplified situation.  Templating `A` on the same type `B` is templated on just makes `A` have lots of template parameters, and I don't want that.

Answer (score 2):

At the time `A<B<TT>>` is instantiated, `B<TT>` is still an incomplete class, so you can't use `B<TT>::tt`.

If the type at issue is a template argument of `B`, then you can extract the template parameter via a traits class:

```
template <typename TT>
struct B;

template<class> struct B_traits;
template<class TT> 
struct B_traits<B<TT>> {
    using tt = TT;
};

template <typename T>
struct A {
   virtual typename B_traits<T>::tt returns_something();
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/88eb865089f5a638).

Comment: Thanks!  A few questions.  Is there any way to define this without a "traits" class?  (reordering definitions or something similar).  Also, why do you forward declare B_traits immediately before you define B_traits?

Comment: @AndrewSpott 1) Not really; Since `B<TT>` derives from `A<B<TT>>`, you have to extract `TT` while `B<TT>` is an incomplete type; that necessitates using a separate class (or something equally annoying). 2) The first line is a declaration of the primary template `B_traits`; the second is a partial specialization of `B_traits` for actual `B`s.